# Use more than four components in OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I know it is simply not possible to have more than the four built-in texture components. At least directly. Generally, the proposed solution is simple - use multiple textures. However, I think that it is not optimal. Let's look at an example.

Let's say there is a basic material format that has the following properties:

1. albedo - 3 components
2. normal - 3 components
3. roughness - 1 component
4. metallness - 1 component

The simplest way to store this data would be to use 4 diffrent textures with respectively 3, 3, 1, and 1 components. This is inefficient for at least two reasons:

1. Most probably the GPU does not actually store the first two textures with only 3 components, but with four, as most GPUs align 3 component vectors, matrices, textures to four components.
2. Getting all the data in the shader requires 4 texture samples

The common way to deal with this would be to pack the data in the least amount if textures possible that also nicely align. In this case it could be put in two textures with 4 components each. This solves the first issue of wasted memory, but the second one still exists as it is still required to do 2 texture samples to read the data. 2 samples is not really a lot, but what if it could be reduced to just one?

My idea is to pack all 6 components in one texture. How? `GL_RGB16_SNORM`. It is a texture internal format that albeit having only 3 components, could actually fit 6 because each pixel is 6 bytes.

So my question is:

1. Would it be possible to upload the data as 6 components to such a texture and somehow read it in the shader.
2. Would it be faster to use this packing or just stick to using two separate textures.
3. Is there a different, better approach to this?

Comment: "*2 samples is not really a lot, but what if it could be reduced to just one?*" You act as if the cost of a texture sample is in calling a function, rather than what that function has to actually *do*. The difference between calling a function twice and calling one function that does twice the work is pretty negligible.

Comment: With your idea, you can't interpolate between pixels automatically.

Comment: @NicolBolas what about data locality. Isn't it faster to read 6 bytes from one texture, than to read 3 bytes from two textures, at two different memory locations?

Comment: @user253751 That's right. I didn't think of that. I hope there is a different solution, then.

Comment: You already have a different solution.

Comment: @user253751 I meant that I hope there is a way to get around this issue and somehow store more than 4 values in a texture anyway.

Comment: Well there isn't.

Comment: You might notice OpenGL only has vectors up to size 4.

Comment: @user253751 I assume you meant that GLSL has vector up to size 4. Yes, I noticed that. However just because there is no built in way to store more than 4 components per pixel it doesn't mean that it is impossible to come up with a clever workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [array texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture) & sample at the same (u,v) location in the other layers to retrieve your extra texture channel data.

Comment: I did consider that approach, however I am not sure if it is going to be more efficient than using two textures. Is it more efficient to make multiple samples in the same array texture, rather than to sample multiple textures?

Comment: Saves you glBindTexture() calls.